How to resolve imported types to their actual definition with ts-morph
I'm trying to see if its possible to use ts-morph to auto-generate documentation, for a few specific files.
Assume I have the following file:
import { SomeInterface } from 'some-module';

const myVariable: SomeInterface;

With ts-morph I can use sourceFile.getVariableDeclarations() to get an array of all defined variables. I can then easily do variableDeclaration.getName() to get the name of the variable, but if I use variableDeclaration.getType().getText(), I get import("/Users/user/projects/project/node_modules/some-module").SomeInterface.
Is there a way to get the actual type, without having to parse the string with regex to get the path, then trying to find the type in the imported source file?
